# Capture output from subprocess, but with tags from code that produced it

Tags: python, parsing, console, subprocess

### Background

I'm writing a html book about doing things in python. It contains a ton of text and code interspersed with output. I want to be able to modify my python code at any time, and have one script to batch update all the HTML files with the changes.

Since I'll have tons of html files and tons of python snippets, I can't copy and paste from python into HTML manually every time I change something. that will be a nightmare.

**Edit:**

So I have two complimentary files: a python file that contains the logic, and an HTML file that is the tutorial for that python code. I'd like to be able to edit my python files at will, and tag them so that my HTML file can be updated too.

At the moment, when I update my python code, I just run a separate python script that looks in both files for matching tags, and copies the python code between its tags over to the HTML between its matching tags. I have many such tags throughout the files. I also have many such pairs of files.

the tags are ^tagname and end with ^/tagname

However, this only works for the code itself, not the code's output. I'd like to also be able to (if desired) copy the output from the tagged python over to to the html as well, and have it appear inside a slightly modified tag.

I was thinking for output &tagname and &/tagname.

**End Edit**

But getting the output from the python files to do the same thing is proving to be quite difficult.

---

My python code is: (testCode.py)

```
#%%
# ^test
x=1
print(x)
# ^/test


#%%
print("this output I don't care about")

#%%
# ^test2
y=2
print(y)
# ^/test2
```

So, the test and test2 tags are how I want to split the code up.

---

My html looks like this:

```
<p> Some text explaining the purpose of the python code in test1 </p>
<!--^test-->

<!--^/test-->



<p> some more text explaining about test2</p>
<!--^test2-->

<!--^/test2-->
```

The code between test1 tags in python file get copied between the comments above. And the same for test 2.

---

Here's a screenshot of what I have so far in my actual html document. It looks great, but it's missing the output.

[image]

---

The problem is I can't figure out to split up the **output** based on tags inside comments in the code.  I need to use these tags to split the output into chucks associated with each tag.

---

### Desired output

My desired output is a string such as the following:

```
# ^test
1
# ^/test

this is output I don't care about

# ^test2
2
# ^/test2
```

---

### Attempt

I've successfully captured the output of the file into a string using:

```
python_file = 'testCode.py'
process_result = subprocess.run(['python', './' + python_file], capture_output=True, universal_newlines=True)
output = str(process_result.stdout)
```

but obviously that just prints:

```
1
this is output I don't care about
2
```

I am using subprocess because this function will eventually be called in a loop with a list of python files to update the output from.

---

I'm completely stumped about to get access to the appropriate tags and intersperse them in.

Perhaps I'm approaching this wrong.

Comment: This question is still very unclear of what you're actually trying to do. Why do you think that comments would effect the runtime of the code? Why do you even want to write the code like this? You really need to give us more information about the type of output you expect. Right now it seems like you're falling for a common mistake of writing a solution before you get requirements (i.e. writing a problem for the solution rather than a solution for a problem).

Comment: I tried to add some clarification, hopefully this makes sense

Comment: I'm still curious about why you choose to create multiple examples in a single file? This constraint is making the problem much harder to solve than it needs to be. I would opt to just have many self contained simple files `test.py` and `test2.py`. If you need to keep results from one file and have them apply to the next, one option would be to use [`exec`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#exec) for executing the statements (e.g. `exec('x = 1; print(x)', globals(), locals())`)

Comment: Another helpful utility could also be [`contextlib.redirect_stdout`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.redirect_stdout) for capturing stdout/stderr of the code read by `exec` *(from say `test.py` and `test2.py` )* and capturing this in output files *(say `test.out` and `test2.out`)*. You could then have the html generation just expect these files to have been created, and render the text appropriately for your readers.

Comment: In regards to 1, I thought of that. But I found it made it really really hard to write the code cleanly. The real python files are sometimes really complicated with several sections.  As for number 2. That sounds like a close to a perfect solution. I can name the files based on the tag. I guess before each tag I can specify a new output file, and auto generate the code with the IDE when I make a new tag. I’ll try it out and update.

Comment: I've almost got it working I think, but one problem. When I save test.out, I can't find the path to the original python script. since I'm using exec, `__file__`  inside the original script (TestFolder/test.py) is actually returning the location of the automation script (HelperScripts/helper.py). Do you know a way to get the name of the script from which the code originated? I think this is due to exec importing the script text into itself and then running it.

Comment: Thanks so much for all the ideas, that pointed me in the right direction to get a messy but working solution, which I added as an answer. Any feedback would be welcome!

Answer (score 0):

Note: This solution works, but is messy.

### Any suggestions for improvement would be appreciated!

Based on @flakes comment, I've come up with a working solution, but it's not ideal. I'm positive there's a better, more elegant way to do this.

I've decided to reduce the automation a bit to also reduce needed code and complexity.

For each article I now have a folder containing

- ArticleName.py
- ArticleName.html
- ArticleName_helper.py
- OutputFiles [Folder]

Inside ArticleName.py, I have tagged code. If I want to save the output of the code inside the tag, I also create an `OutputTag` object (described below).

```
#%%
out = OutputTag('test', __file__)
# ^test
x=1
print(x)
print("test")
# ^/test
out.done()
```

`OuputTag` object and an object to replace `sdtout` (Stored in a different folder)

```
import os
import sys


#%%
class CustomStdout(object):
    def __init__(self, *files):
        self.files = files

    def write(self, obj):
        for f in self.files:
            f.write(obj)
            f.flush()  # If you want the output to be visible immediately

    def flush(self) :
        for f in self.files:
            f.flush()


#%%
class OutputTag:
    def __init__(self, tag, origin_file):
        origin_dir = os.path.dirname(origin_file)

        if not os.path.exists(origin_dir) :
            raise FileNotFoundError("Origin file does not exist!")

        dir = origin_dir + "/OutputFiles"
        if not os.path.exists(dir):
            os.makedirs(dir)

        file_name = os.path.join(dir, tag + '.txt')
        self.original = sys.stdout
        self.f = open(file_name, 'w')
        # This will go to stdout and the file out.txt
        sys.stdout = CustomStdout(sys.stdout, self.f)

    def done(self):
        self.f.close();
        sys.stdout = self.original
```

Ok so that populates the OutputFiles folder with a bunch of .txt files named after the tags.

Then I run the ArticleName_helper.py script.

1. It has a reference to the py and html files.
2. The helper script looks for code-tags inside ArticleName.html.
3. It searches inside ArticleName.py for matching tags, and copies any code between them.
4. This copied code then replaces any existing text between the tags in the HTML.
5. Similarly, it searches for output tags (&Tag instead of ^Tag) in html.
6. It looks for files in OutputFolder that match the tag name.
7. Then loads the text inside, replacing any text in the html file between the output tags.

In my IDE I have auto code completion. In python, when I type html and press tab it auto generates the following with a multi-cursor ready to overwrite TAG in all 3 spots:

```
out = OutputTag('TAG', __file__)
# ^TAG

# ^/TAG
out.done()
```

similarly in html editing, I have it autocomplete the following when I type py and hit tab:

```
<pre><code class="language-python">
    <!--^TAG-->

    <!--^/TAG-->
</code></pre>
```

And a similar one for output with the ^ replaced by &

## So the current workflow is:

1. Write python file
2. Add tags if wanted
3. Write HTML tutorial, adding comment tags where needed for both input and associated output.
4. Run Python file to update output
5. Run Helper Script
6. HTML file auto populates with code and output where tags were added.

After making edits, just do steps 4-6.

The result!

[image: result screenshot]